# I am using React Testing Library and Jest to test my app. I'm not sure how to test an imported function. I have the following code below:

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-tsx

As you can see, I have a function called `trueFn` that I export into App. I then call it every time I click the button. I'm just unsure how to get jest to mock that function in the test file. How can I make sure the mocked function is called when I click the button?

```
/*
  ./trueFn.js
*/

export const trueFn = () => {
    return true;
}

/*
  App.js
*/

import React from 'react';
import { trueFn } from './trueFn';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Button onClick={trueFn}>Click me</Button>
    )
}

/*
  App.test.js
*/

const getComponent = () => {
    return render (
        <App />
    )
}

describe('App.js Component', () => {
    it('should run trueFn on button click', () => {
        const mockTrueFn = jest.fn();
        const component = getComponent();

        expect(mockTrueFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [spy](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Something like this should work:

```
const trueFn = require('./trueFn.js');

describe('App.js Component', () => {
    it('should run trueFn on button click', () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(trueFn);
        getComponent();

        // do an action to call your button, something like:
        const button = screen.getByTestId('element');
        userEvent.click(button);

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```